# Struts2 :Error after validate method() saying input is missing

Tags: jsp, struts2, include

I am new to struts2, I m having JSP with form action (called on submit) and jsp include at start of page which just return httprequest paramaters (common to all pages kind of menu).

Issue is when I submit the page and got validation error / actionerror , on returning input page of my action , jsp include return an error which @ first time run fine, only error out when validate fails

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! A code example showing the problem would really increase the chance for a helpful answer.

Comment: could you show your struts.xml code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using validation you need a result 'input' which forward to a page when validation method catches error.For eg

```
 <action name="login" class="com.actions.LoginAction">
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>
        <result name="success">/welcome.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/login.jsp</result>
    </action>
```

In the above code login.jsp is the page where i check for validation and so here i want the error message to be displayed.